# Regex selection trailed from last character

Tags: regex

How to select from:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Gfx/Global/FavIcon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

a string ending after `href` closing colon to match:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Gfx/Global/FavIcon/favicon.ico`

I have following expression:

`(link.*shortcut icon.*)(href)../(.*?)\"`

But it selects:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Gfx/Global/FavIcon/favicon.ico"`

instead of:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Gfx/Global/FavIcon/favicon.ico`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input html is only the one line that you are showing in question's description, then your regex will get passed here. Just omit the `\"` from the end using lookahead.

```
(link.*shortcut icon.*)(href)../(.*?)(?=\")
```

But, if your html is huge one, then above regex will not work for you. Try this one:

```
(link[^>]*shortcut icon[^>]*)(href)../([^>\"]*)(?=\")
```

Yet still. The **regex may not proof safe** for few specific htmls. So try some html parser or similar library instead of regex.

Comment: Which few specific htmls you speak of? Are you reffering to differently sorted attributes, values of them in singlequotes etc. problems?

Comment: @Ultra yes, differently sorted attributes.

Comment: It's HTML inputed only by me and users guided to do it in "proper" way as it is for lazy cache refreshing - insated of writing dates in our scripts by hand we can relay on modification date in UNIX ;-)